# Return Http 503 from Apache enabling CORS

Tags: angular, apache

I need that all requests to my Apache are replied with a http 503 error (also OPTION requests).
Apache replies to my Angular application and CORS is needed. I want to return 503 status in order to redirect the user from my application to a maintenance page. So, when in my application I get a http 503 from Apache, I route the user to a specific page.

Right now instead, when I make a call I get this message:

```
Failed to load https://mywebsite/api/v1/loggedUser: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 503.
```

This is my apache configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost server_ip:443>
                ServerName mywebsite.com
                ServerAlias *.mywebsite.com
                SSLEngine on
                SSLProxyEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/public.crt
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private.key
                SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/intermediate.crt

                RewriteEngine On
                #Force maintenance mode returning a 503
                <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
                        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
                </IfModule>
                RewriteRule .* - [R=503,L]               
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: _"Am I doing something wrong?"_ - yes, you are insisting on _"I need that all requests to my Apache are replied with a http 503 error (also OPTION requests)"_, which just won't work with a pre-flighted CORS request. A pre-flight request is the client asking the server, hey mate we cool if I request this here even though I'm not "from" your domain? Answering that with 503 Service Unavailable is of course not going to encourage any client to proceed with the actual request.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks. I solved then replying 200 to OPTIONS and 503 to all others requests. THanks for the hint ;-)